# Xcode 6 Bug? Adding iPhone 6/6 Plus LaunchImage Changes App Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I have my project setup on AutoLayout, works fine with iPhones 4 - 6 Plus.  However, when I add in the LaunchImage for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, the frames and constraints for the entire app no longer take up the entire screen.  Instead, the entire app fits in the top left area of the screen.

If I remove the LaunchImages for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, then the issue goes away and the elements of each View Controller once again have the correct coordinates and sizes.

I am using the following in Images.assets:
 - 2x iOS - Portrait 7,8
 - Retina 4 - Portrait 7,8
 - Retina HD 5.5 Portrait iOS 8
 - Retina HD 4.7 Portrait iOS 8

There are no warnings regarding the asset catalog, and all the LaunchImages are at the correct dimensions.  I have attempted to Migrate the images over but with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you don't provide iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus launch images, iOS 8 simply scales your interface up (makes everything larger to fit).

Once you provide those images, you will now have access to the larger screen resolutions, and just because you use auto-layout, does not mean your views will resize.  If you have constraints that are limiting the height and width of your views, you will get what you are seeing.  I would check on your constraints on your views to make sure they are done properly and allow the view to grow when the screen size is larger than 320 x 568.

Comment: Looks like you're right, and I am going to have to update many of my constraints programatically.  I'm now determining height and width based off of the percent of the screen size I would like for them to take up.  Was really hoping for an alternative that would take less time.